# What is preferred way to code when only header and footer's background is flexible only not content?

Tags: html, css

What is preferred way to code when only header and footer's background is flexible not content?

Currently I use this method? Is there any better way to do this?

```
<header style="background:red>
<div style="width:950px; margin:0 auto">
</div>
</header>

<div id="content" style="width:950px; margin:0 auto">

</div>


<footer style="background:blue>
<div style="width:950px; margin:0 auto">
</div>
</footer>
```

I used inline css just for example

actual mark-up is

```
 <header>
    <div id="header-inner">
    </div>
    </header>

    <div id="content">

    </div>


    <footer>
    <div id="footer-inner">
    </div>
    </footer>
```

**I'm making website for Desktop and iPad both. iPad has fixed width but Desktop can be anything.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

header and footer make 100% width and content fix it a 95% width, so header and footer are flexible.

css:

```
header {
width:100%;
background:#ccc;
}

footer {
width:100%;
background:#ccc;
}

#content {
width:95%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the other way of doing it. Not necessarily better. Your method looks fine.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
    </div>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper { width: 950px; margin: 0 auto; }
header, footer { margin: 0px -9999px; padding: 0px 9999px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add another `<div>` in the `header` and `footer`?

Also please drop the inline css (if it isn't there just for this example).

Other than that your code looks fine with me

Comment: inline css is for example. and we need extra div to keep the content in center, not flexible. I added Image for example